# Monit does not start Node script

Tags: node.js, monit

I've installed and (hopefully) configured Monit creating a new task in `/etc/monit.d` (on CentOS 6.5)

my task file is called `test`:

```
check host test with address 127.0.0.1
    start program = "/usr/local/bin/node /var/node/test/index.js" as uid node and gid node
    stop program  = "/usr/bin/pkill -f 'node /var/node/test/index.js'"
    if failed port 7000 protocol HTTP
        request /
        with timeout 10 seconds
        then restart
```

When I run:

```
service monit restart
```

In my monit logs appears:

```
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:43] info     : monit daemon with pid [21946] killed
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:43] info     : 'nsxxxxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu' Monit stopped
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:47] info     : 'nsxxxxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu' Monit started
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:47] error    : 'test' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[127.0.0.1:7000] via TCP
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:47] info     : 'test' trying to restart
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:47] info     : 'test' stop: /usr/bin/pkill
[CEST Jul  4 09:50:47] info     : 'test' start: /usr/local/bin/node
```

I don't understand why the script does not work, if I run it from command line with:

```
su node # user created for node scripts
node /var/node/test/index.js
```

everything works correctly...

I've followed [this tutorial](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/04/nginx-php-fpm-and-node-js-install-on-centos-5-5/).

How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Did monit fail to start the process or is it just failing to respond to http on port 7000?

Comment: Same issue for me in ubuntu 12. I resolve this with upstart https://codeplease.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/deploying-node-js-production/

Comment: I've used PM2, it's an awesome tool to manage Node.js apps

Answer (score 4):

The same was also not working for me, what i did is made a start/stop script and pass that script in `start program` & `stop program` parameter in monit.
You can found sample of start/stop script from [here](http://werxltd.com/wp/2012/01/05/simple-init-d-script-template/)
Below is my monit setting for node.js app

```
check host my-node-app with address 127.0.0.1
    start program = "/etc/init.d/my-node-app start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/my-node-app stop"
    if failed port 3002 protocol HTTP
        request /
        with timeout 5 seconds
        then restart
    if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```